# Embedding Python into Qt Applications

Tags: windows, qt, python-3.x, mingw, python-embedding

I would like to use Python in my Qt Application.

```
#project.pro
#...
LIBS += -L/path_to_python32/libs/ -lpython32
INCLUDEPATH += /path_to_python32/include
#...
```

Build Issue

```
undefined reference to '_imp__Py_Initialize'
```

Which library have to link or what's the problem?

I use MinGW on x64... oops maybe that's the problem - Python's x64 libs

Comment: Solved. It was about using 64bit lib with 32bit application. Why I have to repeat same mistake all the time :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build your application in Python, use [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro).  If you want integrate a python interpreter into your application use [PythonQt](http://pythonqt.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Thanks for reply... I just want to use Python/C API and that's enough for what I need to do.

Comment: As Python is just a language, why do you want API access without extending Python?